# How can I speed up my Javascript Game Engine

Tags: javascript, html

So, recently, I've been working on a JS/HTML5 Game Engine. Right now I'm calling it DimSumJs, because like [DimSum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dim_sum) isn't a full meal, my framework still runs too slowly to make a full game (it can only run about 250 "objects" despite before slowing down, it becomes very noticeable around 300 "objects"). It uses divs inside an iframe.

A sample game is available at http://pandamochi.x10.bz

just view resources with google chrome and you should be able to find the dimsum.js file

```
//DimSumJS - Open Source Game Engine
//DimSumJS (C) Ruochen Tang
//Can be used commerically, but please give credit
//Constants
var RIGHTKEY = 37;
var UPKEY = 38;
var LEFTKEY = 39;
var DOWNKEY = 40;
var SPACEKEY = 32;
var MASTER_WIDTH = 480;
var MASTER_HEIGHT = 600;

var Game = window.frames[0].document.body;
Game.setAttribute("width",MASTER_WIDTH + "px");
Game.setAttribute("height",MASTER_HEIGHT + "px");
var gl = setInterval("gameLoop();",15);

//Global Vars
var keyDown = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    keyDown[i] = false;
}
var gameState = 1;

//Settings
Game.style.backgroundColor = "#000";

//Key
processKeyEvent = function(event){
        // MSIE hack
        if (window.event)
        {
            event = window.event;
        }

        keyDown[event.keyCode] = true;      
};

releaseKey = function(event){
    // MSIE hack
        if (window.event)
        {
            event = window.event;
        }

    keyDown[event.keyCode] = false;
}
Game.onkeydown = processKeyEvent;
Game.onkeyup = releaseKey;


var GameObjects = new Array();

function GameObject(xx, yy, w, h, i, inc, gs, name, img){

    GameObjects.push(this);

    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.index = i;
    this.currIndex = 0;
    this.increment = inc;
    this.currInc = 0;
    this.x = xx;
    this.y = yy;
    this.depth = 0;
    this.objType = name;
    this.image = img;
    this.xScale = 1;
    this.yScale = 1;
    this.scaleString = "scale(" + this.xScale + "," + this.yScale + ")";
    this.speed = 0;
    this.direction = 0;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravityDirection = 0;
    this.active = true;
    this.visible = true;
    this.bindToRoom = false;
    this.text = "";
    this.color = "#FFF";
    this.gameState = gs;

    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.className=this.objType;
    this.div.style.position="absolute";
    this.div.style.left= this.x + "px";
    this.div.style.top= this.y + "px";
    this.div.style.width= this.width + "px";    
    this.div.style.height= this.height + "px";  
    this.div.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/" + this.image + ")";

    this.div.style[getTransformProperty(this.div)] = this.scaleString;

    Game.appendChild(this.div);
    this.isDiv = true;
    this.classChanged = false;

    this.move = move;
    this.anim = anim;
    this.setScale = setScale;
    this.checkCollisionAt = checkCollisionAt;
    this.objectAt = objectAt;
    this.objectTypeAt = objectTypeAt;
    this.toggleActive = toggleActive;
    this.extend = extend;
    this.unextend = unextend;
    this.isType = isType;
    this.update = update;


    function move(xx,yy){
        this.x += xx;
        this.y += yy;
    }

    function anim(){
        this.currInc += 1;
        if (this.currInc >= this.increment){
            this.currInc -= this.increment;
            this.currIndex += 1;
            if (this.currIndex >= this.index){
                this.currIndex -= this.index;
            }

        }

    }
    function extend(type) {
        this.objType += " " + type;
        this.classChanged = true;
    }

    function unextend(type) {
        this.objType = this.objType.replace( /(?:^|\s)type(?!\S)/ , '' );
        this.classChanged = true;
    }

    function isType(type) {
            return ((' ' + this.objType + ' ').indexOf(' ' + type + ' ') > -1);
    }

    function setScale(xx,yy){
        this.xScale = xx;
        this.yScale = yy;
        this.scaleString = "scale(" + this.xScale + "," + this.yScale + ")";    
    }


    function checkCollisionAt(xx,yy,other){
        //Check For Collision
        xx += this.x;
        yy += this.y;

        if ((xx + this.width > other.x) && (xx < other.x + other.width) && (yy + this.height > other.y) && (yy < other.y + other.height)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function objectAt(xx,yy,solid){
        //Loop All Objects
        for (var i = 0; i < GameObjects.length; i++){
            if (GameObjects[i] != this && this.isDiv){
                if (this.checkCollisionAt(xx,yy,GameObjects[i])){
                    console.log(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }

    function objectTypeAt(xx,yy,type){
        //Loop All Objects
        for (var i = 0; i < GameObjects.length; i++){
            if (GameObjects[i] != this && GameObjects[i].isType(type) && this.isDiv){
                if (this.checkCollisionAt(xx,yy,GameObjects[i])){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function toggleActive(a){
        this.visible = a;
        this.update();
        this.active = a;
    }

    function update(){      
        if ((this.active == false || this.gameState != gameState) && this.isDiv){
            this.isDiv = false;
            Game.removeChild(this.div);
            return;
        }
        else if(!this.isDiv){
            this.isDiv = true;
            Game.appendChild(this.div);
        }

        this.div.style.display = "inline";

        if (this.speed != 0){
            this.x += this.speed*Math.cos(this.direction*Math.PI/180);
            this.y += this.speed*Math.sin(this.direction*Math.PI/180);
        }

        if (this.bindToRoom == true){
            if (this.x < 0){
                this.x = 0;
            }

            if (this.y < 0){
                this.y = 0;
            }

            if (this.x > MASTER_WIDTH-this.width){
                this.x = MASTER_WIDTH-this.width;
            }

            if (this.y > MASTER_HEIGHT-this.height){
                this.y = MASTER_HEIGHT-this.height;
            }
        }

        if (!this.visible && this.isDiv){
            this.isDiv = false;
            Game.removeChild(this.div);
            return;
        }
        if (this.classChanged){
            this.div.className = this.objType;
        }

        this.div.style.zIndex = this.depth;

        this.div.style.color = this.color;
        this.div.innerHTML = this.text;

        this.div.style.left= this.x + "px";
        this.div.style.top= this.y + "px";

        this.div.style[getTransformProperty(this.div)] = this.scaleString;
        this.div.style.backgroundPosition = this.currIndex * this.width +"px 0";


    }
}
function getTransformProperty(element) {

    // Note that in some versions of IE9 it is critical that
    // msTransform appear in this list before MozTransform
    // By ZachAstronaut

    var properties = [
        'transform',
        'WebkitTransform',
        'msTransform',
        'MozTransform',
        'OTransform'
    ];
    var p;
    while (p = properties.shift()) {
        if (typeof element.style[p] != 'undefined') {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Right now, whenever an object is not in the current gameState, becomes inactive, or is not visible, I will remove the div from the game's iframe. I have checks to make sure not to run any unnecessary scripts in the update() function. Is there anyway I can improve my speed?

Comment: <iframe> doesn't really seem very HTML5...

Comment: I would use canvas, but it runs very slowly on iOS

Comment: Please post some code which you believe to be the source of the slowdown and then flag for moderator attention and we'll move it to the code review site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with profilers?  [Google Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html) includes a fairly good one.  When I run your program and start profiling it, Chrome reports that your definition of isType is expensive.

```
function isType(type) {
    return this.objType && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + type + "(\\s|$)").test(this.objType);
}
```

Sure enough, this is expensive.  Dynamically constructing RegExps can be costly.

To avoid that cost, lift out the definition of the regular expression out of isType if you can.  Assuming the set of types is fixed, you can pre-compute the regexps for all the types at toplevel, store them in an object, and then do a simple lookup to get the precomputed regexp.  If you don't know them all up front, you can still cache regexps from prior calls to isType.

```
var priorTypeRegexps = {};
function isType(type) {
    var aRegexp;
    if (! priorTypeRegexps[type]) {
        priorTypeRegexps[type] = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + type + "(\\s|$)");
    }
    aRegexp = priorTypeRegexps[type];        
    return this.objType && aRegexp.test(this.objType);
}
```

Comment: A more efficient way of doing that might be `(' ' + this.objType + ' ').indexOf(' ' + type + ' ') > -1`. That's the one I always use, but it does only accept spaces. +1 anyway for profilers.

Comment: Thank you both for answering! I didn't know how to work the profiler, so thanks! I'll try out both codes and see which one works well. If noone else has any other suggestions, someone can close the question.

Comment: I strongly, strongly urge you to use your profiler.  It's the basic tool used when asking performance-related questions.  Your intuitions on what is expensive or not can be very wrong.  :)  You need to measure.